# Как запустить проект на C++ включайщий sfml?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, sfml

Доброго времени суток коллеги!

Страшно захотелось мне на C++ написать простецкую игру с графическим интерфейсом. 
Нашёл [крайне интересное видео (4 мин)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zH_omFPqMO4) и код к нему. На нём какой-то выдающийся программист в 150 строк пишет тетрис. Проект с картинками [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?redir_token=MDqFx1r0KFfGHS-rlWrVmBJQfaF8MTUyNzE2MjAyMUAxNTI3MDc1NjIx&v=zH_omFPqMO4&q=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fuc%3Fexport%3Ddownload%26id%3D1naW_v6WAWYPgCIWNDskxtBsM84FoaOLh&event=video_description). Код единственного файла привожу ниже:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>
using namespace sf;

const int M = 20;
const int N = 10;

int field[M][N] = {0};

struct Point
{int x,y;} a[4], b[4];

int figures[7][4] =
{
    1,3,5,7, // I
    2,4,5,7, // Z
    3,5,4,6, // S
    3,5,4,7, // T
    2,3,5,7, // L
    3,5,7,6, // J
    2,3,4,5, // O
};

bool check()
{
   for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
      if (a[i].x<0 || a[i].x>=N || a[i].y>=M) return 0;
      else if (field[a[i].y][a[i].x]) return 0;

   return 1;
};


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));  

    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(320, 480), "The Game!");

    Texture t1,t2,t3;
    t1.loadFromFile("images/tiles.png");
    t2.loadFromFile("images/background.png");
    t3.loadFromFile("images/frame.png");

    Sprite s(t1), background(t2), frame(t3);

    int dx=0; bool rotate=0; int colorNum=1;
    float timer=0,delay=0.3; 

    Clock clock;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        clock.restart();
        timer+=time;

        Event e;
        while (window.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if (e.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();

            if (e.type == Event::KeyPressed)
              if (e.key.code==Keyboard::Up) rotate=true;
              else if (e.key.code==Keyboard::Left) dx=-1;
              else if (e.key.code==Keyboard::Right) dx=1;
        }

    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down)) delay=0.05;

    //// <- Move -> ///
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)  { b[i]=a[i]; a[i].x+=dx; }
    if (!check()) for (int i=0;i<4;i++) a[i]=b[i];

    //////Rotate//////
    if (rotate)
      {
        Point p = a[1]; //center of rotation
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
          {
            int x = a[i].y-p.y;
            int y = a[i].x-p.x;
            a[i].x = p.x - x;
            a[i].y = p.y + y;
          }
        if (!check()) for (int i=0;i<4;i++) a[i]=b[i];
      }

    ///////Tick//////
    if (timer>delay)
      {
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) { b[i]=a[i]; a[i].y+=1; }

        if (!check())
        {
         for (int i=0;i<4;i++) field[b[i].y][b[i].x]=colorNum;

         colorNum=1+rand()%7;
         int n=rand()%7;
         for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
           {
            a[i].x = figures[n][i] % 2;
            a[i].y = figures[n][i] / 2;
           }
        }

        timer=0;
      }

    ///////check lines//////////
    int k=M-1;
    for (int i=M-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        int count=0;
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            if (field[i][j]) count++;
            field[k][j]=field[i][j];
        }
        if (count<N) k--;
    }

    dx=0; rotate=0; delay=0.3;

    /////////draw//////////
    window.clear(Color::White); 
    window.draw(background);

    for (int i=0;i<M;i++)
     for (int j=0;j<N;j++)
       {
         if (field[i][j]==0) continue;
         s.setTextureRect(IntRect(field[i][j]*18,0,18,18));
         s.setPosition(j*18,i*18);
         s.move(28,31); //offset
         window.draw(s);
       }

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
        s.setTextureRect(IntRect(colorNum*18,0,18,18));
        s.setPosition(a[i].x*18,a[i].y*18);
        s.move(28,31); //offset
        window.draw(s);
      }

    window.draw(frame);
    window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Вопрос прост:** как запустить этот код в дебагере? Что нужно для этого сделать? Я открыл вижуалку, а оно даже кнопки *build-rebuild* не имеет. Не понятно. Вроде и точку входа имеет (`main`) приложение, а запустить не получается.

Comment: А вы с С++ знакомы? Т.е. имеете представление как в нем организовано хранение исходного кода, какие этапы включает компиляция?

Comment: @VTT Вы знаете я написал для нужд предприятия три проекта в mfc, но я не уверен что могу ответить утвердительно на ваш вопрос. Если вам есть что сказать - просветите пожалуйста.

Comment: Я к тому, что перед созданием проекта у вас уже должно быть четкое понимание (1) какие директивы препроцессора надо объявить (2) какие заголовочные файлы надо подключить и где они у вас лежат (3) какие библиотеки следует прилинковать и где они у вас лежат (т.е. что вам понадобится на разных этапах компиляции). А как эти шаги настраиваются (и прочие опции компиляции) можно посмотреть в документации к вашей IDE / системе сборки.

Comment: @VTT вы разбираетесь, я это вижу. А вы бы мне готовое решение не подкинули бы, с разъяснением что нужно сделать?

Comment: Ну вот уже [есть сжатый официальный гайд](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php). Но вообще тут "лучше день потерять, потом за пять минут долететь".